# manipulating a link list in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I am beginner to linked lists. Initially I created a one node link list and tried to display its data but It was not being displayed coz of the 
    `while(temp1!=NULL)` condition.
then I tried to take a number of inputs in a loop but now I get the error of unhandled exception, here is my code:

```
struct node
{
int data;
node* next;
};

//Initializing a NULL pointer for head
    node *head=NULL;

//create a temporary node 
    node *temp; 

//allocate space for node 
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

//Initilaizing avariable of node type to store data
node info;
for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
cout<<"Enter Data\t";
cin>>info.data;

//Store data(First Field)
temp->data=info.data;

//Store the address of the head pointer(Second Field)
temp->next=head;

//Converting temp into head since we are adding data from front
    temp=head;
}
  //==============Traversing the Link List=====================//
//Declaring a temporary pointer
 node *temp1;

//Assigning the address of head to temp1
temp1=head;

//Loop to traverse the list
cout<<"the data"<<endl;
while(temp1!=NULL)
{
    cout<<"the data is"<<endl;
    cout<<temp1->data<<endl;
    temp1=temp1->next;
}
```

Comment: Where is the `free` ?  And why malloc in C++ ???

Answer (score 6):

Here's the problem

```
temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); 
//Initilaizing avariable of node type to store data
node info;
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    cout<<"Enter Data\t";
    cin>>info.data;
    //Store data(First Field)
    temp->data=info.data;
    //Store the address of the head pointer(Second Field)
    temp->next=head;
    //Converting temp into head since we are adding data from front
    temp=head;
}
```

You are trying to build a list of three items, so you must allocate *three* nodes. But the code above only allocates one node. You need to move the call to `malloc` inside the loop so it gets called three times.

Comment: @ John ,Thanks:) the input issue has been resolved,however my code still isn't displaying the data,from what I understand the while loop is not being executed,could you help me out???

Comment: If you look at your code you have `head = NULL;`. Nowhere in your code do you change the value of head. So it is still NULL when you get to your while loop. `temp=head;` should be `head=temp;` I would say.

Answer (score 1):

If this is C++ don't use malloc, if this is C, don't use cout. You are mixing up the two languages in poor coding.

The fist thing you have to think every time you call `malloc` is "when will I free?" and the first thing you must thing before typing `new` is "when will I delete?".

The second thing to think about is "who is responsible for the item life": is it the main that "own" the whole list, or are items owing each other? Or is it something else (i.e. the list itself is an object, not just the items)

At this point, think on two classes: a `node` carrying a value, and a `list` hosting nodes and providing methods to buy and dismiss a node, an to walk through the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

You are allocating only one node , while you need to allocate three
hence this statement should in loop so that memory can be allocated for every node

Answer (score 0):

do it as--->

```
node *head=NULL;
node *temp,*ptr;
temp=ptr=NULL
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
     temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
     cout<<"Enter Data\t";
     cin>>info.data;
     //Store data(First Field)
     temp->data=info.data;
     //Store the address of the head pointer(Second Field)

      //Converting temp into head since we are adding data from front
      if(head== NULL)
      {
        head=temp;
        temp->next=NULL;
        ptr=temp;
       }
      else
      {
          ptr->next=temp;
          temp->next=NULL;
          ptr=temp;
      }
}
```

Now the list is filled & head is pointing to the very first node so u can access it.

Comment: @ akp,Don't you think that your code is inserting data from the back of the link list?

Comment: @AaymanKhalid yes its inserting the data from back...but u haven't specified where the node should be inserted!!! u can modify as u wish...>>

Comment: could you help me understand the insertion from front,coz from what I understand head is at the end of the list after the insertion of data,am I right?